# SWIG from c++ to python: undefined symbol import problem

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig

I'm encountering some problems in swigging a c++ function to python. My function is contained in my header file:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>      
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>   
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <iostream>   
#include <Eigen/Core>

// Classes used in the wrapped function DLM
#include "Param.h"
#include "Wingsegment.h"
#include "Modes.h"
#include "IPS.h"

#include "Dlattice.h"
#include "Strmesh.h"
#include "Aeromesh.h"

void DLM( std::string DLM_inputfile, std::vector<double> 
   &Qhh_std_real, std::vector<double> &Qhh_std_imag,  
      std::vector<double> &omegavector_std, int &nModes, int 
       &nOmega ); 


std::string return_format_modes() ;
```

Just for clarification I'll insert some part of the `DLM.cpp` code:

```
#include "DLM.h"
std::string format_modes;    // Global variable

void DLM( std::string DLM_inputfile, std::vector<double> 
&Qhh_std_real, std::vector<double> &Qhh_std_imag,  
std::vector<double> &omegavector_std, int &nModes, int 
&nOmega )  
{     
 const std::string config_file_name = DLM_inputfile;

 Param PARAM;
 PARAM.read_DLM_input( config_file_name);
 PARAM.read_General();
 PARAM.read_Aerogeneral(); //<-- here apparently the issue
 ...
 };
```

Given this c++ function, here is the file for SWIG `pyDLM_Cpp.i`:

```
%module pyDLM_Cpp
%{
/* Every thing in this file is being copied in 
 wrapper file. We include the C header file necessary
 to compile the interface */
#include "./dlm/DLM.h"
#include "./dlm/Param.h"
%}
%include "std_vector.i";
%include "std_string.i";

namespace std {
    %template(DoubleVector)  vector<double>;
}; 

%include "./dlm/DLM.h";
%include "./dlm/Param.h";
```

the Makefile I use (which looks like working file is):

```
EIGEN_PATH = path/to/eigen
INCLPATH =  -I$(EIGEN_PATH)
all:
     swig -c++ -python -Wall pyDLM_Cpp.i
     g++ -O2 -c -std=gnu++11 -fPIC ./dlm/DLM.cpp  
          $(INCLPATH)  
     g++ -O2 -c -std=gnu++11 -fPIC pyDLM_Cpp_wrap.cxx - 
         I/usr/include/python2.7 $(INCLPATH)
     g++ -O2 -shared -fPIC DLM.o pyDLM_Cpp_wrap.o -o 
          _pyDLM_Cpp.so
```

Now, when I try to import my function into python the error I get is:

```
ImportError: ./_pyDLM_Cpp.so: undefined symbol: 
  _ZN5Param16read_AerogeneralEv
```

Now, the function Param::read_Aerogeneral() is declared in `Param.h` as member of the object Param defined in the first lines of the `DLM.cpp` file and is not directly used in Python which calls only the function DLM in the DLM.h file, so I don't get why this particular issue. Plus, I saw online many similar problems but none of the proposed solutions worked. 
Anyone can help on how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance

PS: the code uses internally the library Eigen as it can be seen in the different proposed files.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, make sure you do some research on what the error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T. Herzke's answer was actually helpful. Found out that the symbol in question `_ZN5Param16read_AerogeneralEv` is only defined in `Param.o` which is built if specified as following in the makefile:

```
g++ -O2 -c -std=gnu++11 -fPIC ./dlm/DLM.cpp ./dlm/Param.cpp 
      $(INCLPATH) # need to add the Param.cpp
```

And then add the `Param.o` to the `_pyDLM_Cpp.so` building:

```
g++ -O2 -shared -fPIC DLM.o Param.o pyDLM_Cpp_wrap.o -o 
      _pyDLM_Cpp.so # need to add the Param.o
```

Building the interface this way doesn't give any error when imported into my python routine.

Answer (score 3):

The dynamic linker complains that the symbol `_ZN5Param16read_AerogeneralEv` is not defined.

You are convinced that it is defined in object file `DLM.o`.

Please check whether it is actually defined in that object file with

```
 nm DLM.o | grep _ZN5Param16read_AerogeneralEv
```

If you see an entry starting with `T`, then it is defined in this file. If you only see an entry starting with `U`, or no entry at all, then it is not defined in this file.

If it is defined, try reordering the object files on the linker command line (let `DLM.o` be the last object).

It is more likely that the symbol is actually not defined there. You need to investigate why this is the case and fix it.